# Is there an issue with EF6.x when creating TPT inheritance across multiple projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Consider the following scenario (using EF6 with VS 2017 in a code first workflow).

I have a base abstract entitybase class (which provides an ID property and a few other properties that would be applicable to all entities).

I have a contact class that inherits entitybase.  it too is abstract and provides common properties for the typical business objects that the application will use (for example Customer and Supplier) and that provides things like First and Last Name.

Finally there are the separate Customer and Supplier classes that inherit from Contact.

If I place all of these components in a single project, add the EF Nuget package, Enable migrations and then add a migration I get the Table per type table structure that I am expecting (a Contact table and separate Customer and Supplier tables linked by foreign key to the contacts table).  The business rule that a contact can be both a Customer and Supplier is satisfied.

Now in a large scale application it is highly likely that the common base class may well be in a separate project containing items common to many different contexts.  The contact, Customer and supplier classes may well be in their own separate project and the Contacts context in its own separate project.

If I replicate that scenario and then enable and add migrations I end up with separate Customer and Supplier classes with their own copies of the fields they inherited from Contact, but no Contacts table.  Immediately the business rule has been broken.

Is this a known issue with EF6?

If this were for a small application I'd simply bundle everything into one project (all be it separated into various folders) however I'm looking to remodel an existing much larger application along code first lines and breaking the various schemas apart into separate sections which themselves may well be composed of many projects makes more sense.   I may well be doing something wrong as I'm still starting out with code first but I'd welcome any thoughts if anyone has either encountered this, or knows how perhaps I should be trying to arrange the component parts to get it to work.

Comment: Jus for clarity, `EntityBase` is in one project, `Contact` + derived + context are in second project?

Comment: Entitybase is in one, contact + derived in in a second, context in a third. If you think of it as a, b, and c then c references b which in turn references a. Ed is added to c.

Comment: I see. And what DbSets does the derived context contain - only `DbSet<Contact>` or ? Any fluent configuration?

Comment: DBsets for Customer and supplier only. A small piece of Fluent api to map dot net datetime to sql datetime2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with EF6 base entity discovery process in this scenario (when the entity classes assembly is different than the `DbContext` assembly).

As a rule of thumb, always expose a polymorphic `DbSet` of the inheritance root entity, or explicitly identify it with `Entity<T>()` fluent API.

So either of the following two options will solve the issue:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

or

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```